# While upgrading the spring boot version, stuck with the following error. Pls let me know how to solve this

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data

I'm stuck with the following error while upgrading the spring boot version. Please tell the way to fix this issue.

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] 2022-05-16 13:14:27.170 [main]  TomcatStarter:61 - Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appUserDetailService' defined in file [/Users/sambramhr/Documents/GitHub/DamaAPI/DamaBO/build/classes/java/main/com/dama/bo/security/AppUserDetailService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userLoginServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'smsNotificationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'smsNotificationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kafkaProducer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaProducer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kafkaTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/dama/common/kafka/KafkaProducerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate]: Factory method 'kafkaTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0
```

BUILD.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.6.6'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.boxfuse.client:gradle-plugin-publishing:5.2.4"
    }
    ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.17.1'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.flywaydb.flyway'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'


group = 'com.dama'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':DamaCore')){
            transitive = false
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka')
    compile group: 'org.xhtmlrenderer', name: 'flying-saucer-pdf-itext5', version: '9.1.6'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.6'
    compile group: 'net.sf.jtidy', name: 'jtidy', version: 'r938'
    compile('ognl:ognl:3.1.12')
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.imgscalr', name: 'imgscalr-lib', version: '4.2'
    implementation group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio', version: '8.22.1'
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7')
    compile('com.ancientprogramming.fixedformat4j:fixedformat4j:1.2.2')
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.50'
    implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-s3', version: '1.12.121'
    compile group: 'com.coralogix.sdk', name: 'coralogix-sdk', version: '2.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.coralogix.sdk', name: 'log4j2-appender', version: '2.0.2'
    
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: '5.0.5.RELEASE' 
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.6"
    compile group: 'com.google.zxing', name: 'core', version: '3.3.1'
    
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpg-jdk15on', version: '1.60'
    compile 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.12'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.12'
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    implementation group: 'io.fusionauth', name: 'fusionauth-jwt', version: '5.0.0'
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    compile group: 'org.apache.lucene', name: 'lucene-spellchecker', version: '3.3.0'
    compile group: 'javax.annotation', name: 'javax.annotation-api', version: '1.3.2'
    compile('com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.2.0')
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4'
    compile (group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.1')
            {
                exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-lang3'
            }
    compile (group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'ipp-v3-java-devkit', version: '5.0.2', classifier: 'jar-with-dependencies')
            {
                exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-lang3'
                exclude group: 'commons-beanutils'
            }
                implementation group: 'com.intuit.quickbooks-online', name: 'oauth2-platform-api', version: '6.2.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.pdfbox', name: 'pdfbox', version: '2.0.1'
    
    implementation group: 'com.plivo', name: 'plivo-java', version: '5.5.0'
    implementation group: 'com.messagemedia.sdk', name: 'messages', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-sns', version: '1.11.13'
    compile "com.github.clicksend:clicksend-java-client:1.0.0"

    compile (group: 'com.thelastcheck.commons', name: 'tlc-io-x937', version: '2.3.0'){
            exclude  module: 'com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core'
            exclude module: 'slf4j-over-slf4j'
            exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
            exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-lang3'
                        
}

    compile ('org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox-tools:2.0.1')   
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-imaging', version: '1.0-alpha2'
    implementation group: 'com.twelvemonkeys.imageio', name: 'imageio-tiff', version: '3.6.2'

   implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'

   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
   compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty')
   implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
   
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.10.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-easymock
    testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-easymock', version: '1.7.1'
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.vintage/junit-vintage-engine
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.8.2'
    
    
}

war {
    enabled = true
    from 'aws_ebextensions'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but PDFBox is at 2.0.26 .

Comment: If the question form prompts you to provide for more text, then heed that warning, and don't add garbage (like a lot of periods) to the question to make that warning go away.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting similar error. You can remove the org.codehaus.jackson and use com.fasterxml.jackson in following ways:-
Following are some of the changes identified between Jackson 1.9.x and Jackson 2.9.8

1. org.codehaus.jackson changed to com.fasterxml.jackson
2. org.codehaus.jackson.map changed to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
3. SerializationConfig.Feature changed and spitted to SerializationFeature,MapperFeature
4. DeSerializationConfig.Feature changed and splitted to DeSerializationFeature,MapperFeature
5. AnnotationIntrospector.Pair changed to AnnotationIntrospectorPair
6. SerializationConfig.withAnnotationIntrospectro(...) changed to SerializationConfig.with(...)
7. ObjectMapper.getSerilizationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(...) changed to ObjectMapper.addMixIn(....)
8. JSonSerialize.include changed to JSonInclude
9. ObjectMapper.readValue(JSonNode,...) changed to OjbjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.treeAsTokens(JSonNode),...)